# Why is "got" used in this context?

Tags: word-choice, passive-voice, past-simple, perfect-constructions

> Our students got selected in top MNC

My question is why  is 'got' used so often in sentences of this type?
Can I use some another word like 'was' in place of 'got'?
Would it be correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's a common use. You could also say "our students **were** selected" or "our students **have been** selected" and either one would be both correct and easily understood.

Answer (score 1):

This structure of *get*-passive is rare in all registers, but occasionally occurs in conversations. The difference between *be-passive* and *get-passive* is that the former expresses a state whereas the latter is more dynamic, describing the proccessing of getting into that state.

> Our students were selected(=our students were in a state of being selected)
>
> Our students got selected(=our students were in the proccess of becoming selected)

*Get-passive* usually occurs in conversations, in a written register, we usually use *become*.

---

*Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English, 6.7.2*